# Label not found

Tags: avr, bascom

I have a problem with my Bascom project.

First, this is my code:

```
$regfile = "m128def.dat"
$CRYSTAL=8000000
$hwstack = 512
$swstack = 512
$framesize = 512

Config Porte = Output : Data_disp_low Alias Porte           'DB0 - DB7
Config Portf = Output : Data_disp_high Alias Portf          'DB8 - DB15
Rs_disp Alias Portd.0 : Config Rs_disp = Output                'Command/Data pin
Wr_disp Alias Portd.1 : Config Wr_disp = Output             'Write pin
Rd_ssd1963 Alias Portd.2 : Config Rd_ssd1963 = Output
Res_disp Alias Portd.4 : Config Res_disp = Output           'Reset pin
Res_disp = 1
Cs_disp Alias Portd.3 : Config Cs_disp = Output             'Chip Select
Cs_disp = 0


Const Color_bgr = 0
Const Portrait = 0                                          '1=Portrait, 0=Landscape
Const Rotate_180 = 0                                        '1=Rotated,  0=Not Rotated
Config Submode = New : $include "SSD1963 16bit library.inc" 'Include library
Config Portd.0 = Output

Display_init
Lcd_backlight 160
Lcd_clear Black

Restore A_en_boldfont14x23
   Alcd_txt "Hello" , 320 , 37 , White , Black , 0
wait 5
```

I want to restore a file and show it in my GLCD but the IDE shows this error to me:

```
Error : 61    Line :   28    Label not found [A_EN_BOLDFONT14X23]  , in File : D:\AVR\bascomprj\lcd4inch\noname2.bas
```

and this is strange because I put `[A_EN_BOLDFONT14X23]` in my project's file.

Does anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The message says that there is no data label "A_EN_BOLDFONT14X23" found in your project file. If you want to access data stored on the program memory you have to define a label. Than you could access the data by for example read You can't access a file stored in your project directory.
[Bascom help restore](http://avrhelp.mcselec.com/index.html?restore.htm%22BASCOM%20restore%22)

Example:

```
Restore Data_to_restore
Read S : Print S  'read an print "display text 1"
Read S : Print S

Data_to_restore:
Data "display text 1" , "display text 2"
```